# Let $x_1, x_2, \cdots x_n $ be real numbers $x_i > 1$, such that $x_1x_2 \cdots x_n = 2^n $.

Tags: inequality

Find the maximum value of $$\displaystyle  {\frac {1}{x_1} + \frac {1}{x_2} + \cdots + \frac {1}{x_n}}$$

Every time I am approching this problem by RMS-AM-GM-HM Inequality  i am getting the minimum value..How to solve it

Comment: are you sure you typed this right?  Perhaps it is instead $x_i \geq 1$ ?  As is the set of allowable values of $x_i$ isn't compact and it isn't obvious that a maximum even exists.

Comment: Is the number $n$ fixed? Try first with  $n=2$.

Comment: The _supremum_ of this sum would appear to be $n-1+2^{-n}$.This can never be attained (it requires $n-1$ of the $x_i$ to be $1$), but it can be approached as close as you like with $(x_i)=(1+\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon,\ldots,2^n/(1+\varepsilon)^{n-1})$.

Comment: Yeah user8675309 i typed the question right. Actually it was in a book.

Comment: so the correct answer is "the maximum does not exist"

Answer (score 2):

Replace the condition $x_i>1$ for the moment by $x_i\geq1$. Assume $x_1>1$, $\>x_2>1$. I claim that
$${1\over x_1}+{1\over x_2}<{1\over1}+{1\over x_1x_2}\ .\tag{1}$$
*Proof.* We have to show that $x_1+x_2<1+x_1x_2$. To this end write $x_i=1+y_i$ with $y_i>0$.We then have to show that
$$(1+y_1)+(1+y_2)<1+(1+y_1)(1+y_2)\ ,$$
which is obvious.$\quad\square$

From $(1)$ it follows that when $x_1$, $x_2>1$ then we can increase the objective function by replacing $x_1$, $x_2$ by $1$ and $x_1x_2$, having the same product, hence the $n$-tuple remains admissible. This shows that the objective function is largest when $x_1=\ldots=x_{n-1}=1$ and $x_n=2^n$. The maximal value therefore is $n-1+2^{-n}$. When we have the condition $x_i>1$ we don't have a maximum, but only a supremum of the same value.

Comment: You got there first! My (now deleted) post was identical, for certain values of 'identical'.

Answer (score 1):

$$G.M\ge HM$$
$$\left(x_1x_2x_3\cdots\cdots x_n\right)^\frac{1}{n}\ge\dfrac{n}{\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}\cdots\cdots}$$

$$\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}\cdots\cdots\frac{1}{x_n}\ge\dfrac{n}{2}$$

So $\dfrac{n}{2}$ should be the minimum value.

Comment: why there is downvote, am I missing anything?

Comment: Even you put $x_i$ = 1 , you got n only

Comment: I didn't down vote, but it may have been done because it seems you have reciprocal of the HM part, e.g., as explained at [Harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean). Also, I believe that something like $n-1$ is the maximum you can get by setting all $x_i$ to be very near $1$ except for one value which is near $2^n$.

Comment: @DragunityMAX You cannot have all $x_i=1$ because they are $>1$ and their  product is $2^n$...

Comment: You showed that the minimum is at least $n/2$.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I made a small mistake while calculating H.M.

Comment: ok, sorry got confused, let me think of some other way.

Comment: Lett $x_1\approx 2^n$ and all others close to $1$. So the sum is close to $n-1+1/2^n$

Comment: @JeanMarie I just give an upper bound

Comment: @DragunityMAX But you have to comply with condition product = $2^n$...

Comment: The question is about finding the maximum value (plus you only prooved it is a lower bound if I am not mistaken).

Comment: In the question it is clearly mentioned to find the maximum value not minimum value

Answer (score 1):

assuming OP fixes the domain to allow $x_i \geq 1$,

the nicest proof I can think of is a bit  sophisticated: the answer is to consider log reciprocal x elements, i.e.   $y_i := \log\big(\frac{1}{x_i}\big)$
the optimal vector is

$$\mathbf y' = \begin{bmatrix}
\log\big(\frac{1}{1}\big)\\ 
\log\big(\frac{1}{1}\big)\\ 
\vdots  \\
\log\big(\frac{1}{1}\big)\\ 
\log\big(\frac{1}{2^n}\big)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
\vdots  \\
0\\ 
\log\big(\frac{1}{2^n}\big)
\end{bmatrix}$$
because $\mathbf y' \succeq \mathbf y$ for any feasible $\mathbf y$ where $\succeq$ denotes (strong) majorization. I.e.  If you consider the sum of the first k items in $\mathbf y'$ for $k\in\{1,2,...,n-1\}$ it is zero which is at least as big as any k partial sum for any other configuration.

And
$$\mathbf 1^T \mathbf y' = \mathbf 1^T\mathbf y= y_1 + y_2 + ... + y_n = \log\big(\frac{1}{2^n}\big)$$
in all cases.

The mapping $u \mapsto e^u$ is (strictly) convex, and let $g$ be given by $g\big(\mathbf y\big) = e^{y_1} + e^{y_2} + ... + e^{y_n}$. The function $g$ is thus Schur convex and
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 1\right)+\frac{1}{2^n} = n-1 + \frac{1}{2^n} = g\big(\mathbf y'\big) \geq g\big(\mathbf y\big)$$
for any allowable $\mathbf y$